# Replicate the pipe function in a minishell - Issues hanging, also sequence of commands

Tags: c, pipe

I am attempting to create a minishell project. I have completed the parsing of commands into a list/tokens. When I execute a command with pipes I experience some strange behaviour.
For example, if I type into the minishell "echo hi | wc" the output is correct however an empty line is displayed afterwards in which I am still able to put in another command for it to execute, before it goes back to my original process.
**Is it hanging in a process?**

```
➜  minishell git:() ✗ make; ./minishell
$> echo hi | wc
$>        1       1       3
echo test
test
$>
```

Also given my below code, I am concerned that it will wait for the completion of one process before proceeding to the next. For example, if I execute the following command it should immediately return the results of the word count of Makefile first and then continue sleeping, however it seems my code sleeps first, then returns result.
**How can I ensure my code executes exactly as it would in bash?**

```
➜  minishell git:() ✗ make; ./minishell
$> sleep 6 | cat Makefile | wc
$>      149     499    4252
```

I have provided the below snippet, and can share any further info if needed. Due to size of codes, I cannot provide a minimum replicable sample. Any help would be highly appreciated!
(Please ignore commented out sections, i.e 'grid', it shouldn't impact code performance.)

```
 int GLOBAL_ERROR = 0;

 void   close_pipes(int pipes[1000][2] , int lines)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < lines - 1)
    {
        close(pipes[i][0]);
        close(pipes[i][1]);
        i++;
    }
}

int assign_pi(t_mhstruct **mh)
{
    t_token *current;
    int     idx;

    current = (*mh)->token;
    idx = 0;
    while (current)
    {
        while (current->type != PIPELINE && current)
        {
            current->pi = idx;
            if (current->next)
                current = current->next;
            else
                break;
        }
        if (current)
            current = current->next;
        idx++;
    }   
    return (idx);
}

int get_args_size_pipes(t_token *tmp)
{
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    if (!tmp)
        return (0);
    while (tmp && tmp->type != PIPELINE)
    {
        i++;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return (i);
}

char    **get_args_pipes(t_token *token, t_mhstruct *mh)
{
    char    **out;
    int     i;
    (void) mh;

    i =get_args_size_pipes(token);
    out = (char **)malloc((i + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    if (!out)
        return (NULL);
    i = 0;
    while (token && token->type != PIPELINE)
    {
        out[i] = ft_strdup(token->data);
        token = token->next;
        i++;
    }
    out[i] = NULL;
    return (out);
}


void    execve_commands_pipes(t_token *curr, t_mhstruct *mh)
{
    char    **arg;
    char    **env;
    char    *path;
    int     out;
    int     pid;

    path = NULL;
    out = 0;
    env = get_env_array(mh);
    arg = get_args_pipes(curr, mh);
    if (check_path(arg[0], env, &path) == 0)
    {
        if (access(arg[0], R_OK) == 0)
            path = arg[0];
        else
        {
            free(env);
            free(arg);
            return (pr_err(mh, 127, gemsg(mh->emsg[11], mh->emsg[12], arg[0])));
        }
    }
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
        execve(path, arg, env);
    waitpid(pid, &GLOBAL_ERROR, 0);
    return;
}


void    set_pipe(t_token *curr, int pipes[1000][2], int i, int lines, int screen)
{

    (void) curr;
    (void) screen;
    if (i == 0)
    {
        close(pipes[i][0]);
        dup2(pipes[i][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pipes[i][1]);
    
    }
    else if (i != 0 && i != lines - 1)
    {
        dup2(pipes[i - 1][0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(pipes[i - 1][0]);
        dup2(pipes[i][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pipes[i][1]);
    }
    else if (i == lines - 1)
    {
        close(pipes[i - 1][1]);
        dup2(pipes[i - 1][0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(pipes[i - 1][0]);
    }
    
}

void    do_pipe_forks(t_mhstruct **mh, int pipes[1000][2], int  i, int  lines, int screen)
{
    int     pid;
    t_token *curr;
    (void) screen;
    curr = (*mh)->token;
    while (curr && curr->pi != i)
        curr = curr->next;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        
        set_pipe(curr, pipes, i, lines, screen);
        close_pipes(pipes, lines - 1);
        execve_commands_pipes(curr, *mh);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void    do_pipes(t_mhstruct **mh, char **grid, int lines)
{
    int screen = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    int i;
    int pipes[1000][2];
    (void) grid;
    
    i = 0;
    while (i < lines - 1) 
    {
        pipe(pipes[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < lines)
    {
        do_pipe_forks(mh, pipes, i, lines, screen);
        i++;
    }
    close_pipes(pipes, lines);
}


int launch_pipes(t_mhstruct **mh)
{
    int     lines;
    char    **grid = NULL;
    
    lines = assign_pi(mh);

    // grid = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char **) * (lines + 1));
    // if (!grid)
    //  return (1);
    // create_grid(grid, lines, mh);
    do_pipes(mh, grid, lines);

    // free_all(grid);
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I type into the minishell "echo hi | wc" the output is correct

Are you sure?

> however an empty line is displayed afterwards in which I am still able to put in another command for it to execute, before it goes back to my original process.

No, I don't think so. Look carefully: what's that `$>` at the beginning of the line with the `wc` output?  It's certainly not part of `wc`'s normal output. Isn't it your shell's prompt?

So what's happening is that your shell is not waiting for the pipeline to complete before printing the prompt for the next command.  Then there's a newline at the end of `wc`'s output, advancing the cursor to the next line.  So ...

> **Is it hanging in a process?**

No, not at all.  The opposite, in fact: your shell is proceeding too soon, without waiting for the pipeline to finish.

> if I execute the following command it should immediately return the results of the word count of Makefile first and then continue sleeping, however it seems my code sleeps first, then returns result.

Obviously, the timing of the sleep delay relative to the `wc` output being printed is not apparent to us on this side of the screen.  I do observe the same prompting behavior here that I already discussed, but that does not explain the relative timing of the commands in the pipeline.

---

There are several inefficiencies and minor flaws in the code presented, not least that you fork *twice* for each command in a pipeline: once in `do_pipe_forks()` and once in `execve_commands_pipes()`.  Additionally, if the `execve()` call for any command fails, the program falls through and performs a `waitpid(0, &GLOBAL_ERROR, 0)`, which is unwanted.  None of that explains the behavior you describe, though it's related.

**Both the issues you ask about spring from the same general cause: you are waiting for the child processes at the wrong time and in the wrong place.**

Taking the second issue first, `execve_commands_pipes()` launches one command and then *immediately* waits for it to complete.  The commands in a pipeline should run concurrently, at least if they run long enough.  Aside from the parallelism aspect, waiting immediately like that will cause a deadlock if one of the commands other than the last writes enough to its standard output to fill the pipe's buffer, because the process that would have consumed that output will not have started yet.  And this is also what causes your timing issue for `sleep` relative to the subsequent commands in that pipeline.

Now, as I already observed, you fork *twice* for each command in a pipeline.  You wait, too soon, for the children started by `execve_commands_pipes()` to finish, but you do not appear ever to wait at all for the former set.  In the main process, therefore, control returns immediately to the command input loop as soon as the child is launched that will itself launch the last child.  It is not surprising, then, that the main process prints the prompt before the process running the last pipeline command prints anything.

> **How can I ensure my code executes exactly as it would in bash?**

I suggest (*all* of):

- `execve_commands_pipes()` should neither `fork()` nor `waitpid()`.  But, it should `_exit(1)` if its `execve()` call returns.
- On success, `do_pipe_forks()` should return the PID of the forked child in the main process.  It should not return at all in the child process, and it won't, because the call to `execve_commands_pipes()` will not return (see above).
- `do_pipes()` should collect all the PIDs of the child processes, and, *after* closing its copies of all the pipe ends, wait for each child.  This also affords the opportunity to capture the exit status of the last command for use as the exit status of the pipeline, which is in fact what Bash and the POSIX shell do.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I understand what you are suggesting however not certain if I am implementing it correctly (your first two suggestions, I havent explored the third)
I have amended my code accordingly but now the process hangs and only returns the value of wc after I kill the program in another terminal. Have I misunderstood your suggestions? I have posted a new answer to reflect the modified code.

Comment: Please Disregard, I have rectified as per additional answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modified code based on your first two suggestions, I am leaving here in case someone has the same issue.
IMPORTANT, I managed to stop the launch_pipes from prematurely exiting back to my program's main() by introducing a while loop at the end of do_pipes() to wait for child processes to complete

```
// this was added to do_pipes()
while (i < lines)
{
    wait(NULL);
    i++;
}
```

```
//rectified code below

void    execve_commands_pipes(t_token *curr, t_mhstruct *mh, int lines, int pipes[1000][2])
{
    char    **arg;
    char    **env;
    char    *path;
    int     out;

    (void) lines;
(void) pipes;
    path = NULL;
    out = 0;
    env = get_env_array(mh);
    arg = get_args_pipes(curr, mh);
    if (check_path(arg[0], env, &path) == 0)
    {
        if (access(arg[0], R_OK) == 0)
            path = arg[0];
        else
        {
            free(env);
            free(arg);
            return (pr_err(mh, 127, gemsg(mh->emsg[11], mh->emsg[12], arg[0])));
        }
    }
    execve(path, arg, env);
    return ;
}


void    set_pipe(t_token *curr, int pipes[1000][2], int i, int lines, int screen)
{

    (void) curr;
    (void) screen;
    if (i == 0)
    {
        close(pipes[i][0]);
        dup2(pipes[i][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pipes[i][1]);
    
    }
    else if (i != 0 && i != lines - 1)
    {
        dup2(pipes[i - 1][0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(pipes[i][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pipes[i - 1][0]);
        close(pipes[i][1]);
    }
    else if (i == lines - 1)
    {
        close(pipes[i - 1][1]);
        dup2(pipes[i - 1][0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(pipes[i - 1][0]);
    }
    
}

int     do_pipe_forks(t_mhstruct **mh, int pipes[1000][2], int  i, int  lines, int screen, char **grid)
{
    int     pid;
    t_token *curr;
    (void) screen;
    (void) grid;
    (void) lines;
    (void) pipes;
    
    curr = (*mh)->token;
    while ( curr->pi != i)
        curr = curr->next;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        set_pipe(curr, pipes, i, lines, screen);
        close_pipes(pipes, lines);
        execve_commands_pipes(curr, *mh, lines, pipes);
        exit(1);
    }
    return (pid);
}

void    do_pipes(t_mhstruct **mh, char **grid, int lines)
{
    int screen = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    int i;
    int pipes[1000][2];
    (void) grid;
    
    i = 0;
    // printf("lines = %d\n", lines);
    while (i < lines - 1) 
    {
        pipe(pipes[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < lines)
    {
        do_pipe_forks(mh, pipes, i, lines, screen, grid);
        i++;
    }   
    close_pipes(pipes, lines);
    i = 0;
    while (i < lines)
    {
        wait(NULL);
        i++;
    }
}
```